# Json deserialize in Java

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson, fasterxml

I have followinng structure:

```
public class MainDTO {
  private AbstractInferDTO;

  getter and setter;
}

@JsonInfoType(use=Id.Name, include=As.Property, property="type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  Type(value=Infer1DTO.class, name="infer1"),
  Type(value=Infer2DTO.class, name="infer2")
}) 
abstract public class AbstractInferDTO {}

@JsonTypeName("infer1")
public class Infer1DTO extends AbstractInferDTO {
   private String infer1Name;
   getters and setters
}

@JsonTypeName("infer2")
public class Infer2DTO extends AbstractInferDTO {
   private String infer2Name;
   getters and setters
}
```

I have a seriuous trable when I try deserialize this structure. I use POST method, I'm not sure, if Json annotation works for POST method, or only for GET. I have changed this abstract class to normal public class, but I have still error with unrecognized field name AbstractInferDTO["infer1Name"], not market ignorable. I used annotation @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUknown=true) or other way - objectMapper.configure(DeserializeFeature.FAIL_ON_UKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false), but nothing works. 
Could you help me please? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You'll need to post a complete minimal test case, with the JSON as input the code used to deserialize it, and the complete stack trace you get.

Comment: is you are sending json from the client using POST ?

Comment: I use REST API service in Java running on Jetty server or Weblogic server  and also client in java. In my case the json should be formatted as "infer1":{......}, but still "AbstractInferDTO":{....}
I'm not able deserialize this structure after

Comment: Yes, annotations work for `POST` as well. Could you put your example `JSON` payload? How controller's method looks like? Property name in subclass does not fit to property in `Type` annotation.

Comment: I have resolved this problem. Originaly I used Spring MVC and I change it to com.sun.jersey ... and it started work